# How can i go back to previous user conversation once i click the back button In Confirmation Dialog?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am currently working on Bot framework technology, in one of my project I want to go back to the user conversation once I click the back button in FORM like this below figure.
[image]

I know when user enter back in bot framework emulator it will go back immediately but I want above scenario.

How can I resolve the above scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  Can you be more specfiic?

Comment: In the above image when I am click the back button it will not go to previous step conversation dialog. can you please tell me how can I go back to previous conversation once I click the back button.

Comment: So are you saying it worked in the emulator but not elsewhere?

Comment: Even Emulator also it's not working.

Answer (score -1):

If this is a FormDialog, you can add validation steps to each element in the form. In your case, you're probably using a bool "WantsToCreateAccount" or something to the likes of it?

In your FormBuilder code, you'd typically do as I've done here, on a simpler form:

```
public static IForm<UserData> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<UserData>()
            .Message("Before we start, let me ask you a couple of questions")
            .AddRemainingFields()

            .Field(new FieldReflector<UserData>(nameof(IsCustomer))
                .SetValidate(async (state, value) => await ValidateIsCustomerFieldAsync(state, value)))

            .Field(new FieldReflector<UserData>(nameof(HasCustomerId))
                .SetValidate(async (state, value) => await ValidateHasCustomerIdFieldAsync(state, value)))

            .Build();
}
```

The **SetValidate** is the key here, where you can apply whatever logic you'd like after validation of that field, i.e.

```
private static Task<ValidateResult> ValidateHasCustomerIdFieldAsync(UserData state, object value)
{
    if( (SvarAlternativ) value == SvarAlternativ.Nej)
    {
        state.CustomerId = "Kund, har inte Id";
    }
    return Task.FromResult(new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = value });
}
```

Note that a BOOLEAN value is tricky to do validation with because it's a value type that cannot be null, so the validator won't see if it has a "NoValue" or "false" state. Because of this, I just created an enum, where the zero value is the "NoValue" state set by the bot framework:

```
public enum SvarAlternativ
    {
        NoValue,
        Ja, 
        Nej
    }
```

Hope this helps you. Once inside the validation method, you can context.close or do whatever you need.